# Verificação de caractreres especiais

Tags: java

Estou precisando fazer uma verificação em uma string em *java* que permita que o usuário insira acentuação normal, mas, não insira caracteres especiais, tais como: `@#!$!` etc.

Fiz algo parecido para verificar cadastro numérico e em branco utilizando 'matches'. Existe algo semelhante para tal problema?

Comment: Acho que assim `[^\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\\\^\_\`\{\|\}\~\-\0\t\n\r]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como você pretende implementar, mas vou te mostrar duas formas.

Se você quiser verificar caracter por caracter enquanto o usuário vai digitando, você pode utilizar o `Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)`.

Outra forma seria deixar o usuário digitar a `String` completa e fazer a verificação depois utilizando o `StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String)`

Comment: Certo, eu preciso criar um caso de teste que faça a verificação em lista de strings cadastradas. Esse caso de teste tem que verificar se o usuário inseriu algum caractere especial, que não será permitido no sistema. 

Pensei em regex, mas não lembro como era a expressão.

Comment: Ok. Então se você vai verificar a String inteira pode utilizar o StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String)

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma pesquisado nesta função. Obrigado Eduarda!